# Set exit code when receiving SIGTERM in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, sigterm

I’d like to know how I can tell Quarkus to gracefully exit with code 0 upon receiving SIGTERM. I’d still like to react differently (i.e. with an “error” exit code, meaning any number strictly greater than 0) to other exit conditions (such as receiving another signal than SIGTERM).

I have read [Graceful Shutdown](https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#graceful-shutdown) but it does not talk about specifically reacting to SIGTERM.

I suppose that this might involve [`ApplicationLifecycleManager`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.quarkus/quarkus-core/latest/io/quarkus/runtime/ApplicationLifecycleManager.html) or [`Quarkus#asyncExit()`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.quarkus/quarkus-core/3.0.0.Alpha1/io/quarkus/runtime/Quarkus.html#asyncExit(int)) but I’d appreciate having some official doc or some best practices advice rather than try / error, if this is available somewhere. (It is currently unclear to me exactly when and how I am supposed to use `ApplicationLifecycleManager`, if this is indeed the recommended way, or when exactly it is permitted to call `Quarkus#asyncExit()`.)

The reason for this question is that the free hosting plan of Render sends SIGTERM to applications [after 15 minutes of inactivity](https://render.com/docs/free), and Render will consider it an error if the application exits with a non-zero code and will log it accordingly. I’d like to distinguish error conditions from usual, expected activity.

Comment: If you don't find a solution you could run your command as the child of a script or application that forwards the SIGTERM to the application, but eats the return code before exiting itself with code 0. Then Render will get the 0 result from the script/application and everything is dandy.

Comment: Doesn't Quarkus already exit with code `0` when receiving `SIGTERM`?

Comment: Nope. I get an exit code of 143 upon SIGTERM, and 130 if Ctrl+C.